# Can we make an editable formula field in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

Is it possible to make an editable formula field in an object?

Answer (score 5):

A formula field is not editable. You could create an "override" field. This is the formula for the formula field:

```
IF(ISBLANK(OverrideField), "Formula value here", OverrideField)
```

If OverrideField has a value, it is used. Otherwise, the "formula value here" value is used. You should change "formula value here" to an expression that you want in the formula field.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to make formula field as editable.formula field is a read only field.

Answer (score 0):

While not a formula field, you could also create a workflow rule which populates a field only when that field is empty.  Set up the workflow to fire whenever the field value is blank.  Then, as your action, create a field update that sets the field to your formula value.

The downside of this is that the field value will *only* be updated when the record is saved and the field is blank.  This differs from formulas in the fact that a formula field is updated every time the record is viewed.  Depending on your specific use case, this may be an issue.